# How to convert SQL to cakephp query to query from controller

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

This is my SQL query that needs to be converted to cakephp type:

```
select `name` 
from `exams` 
left outer join `exam_results` on `exams`.id = `exam_results`.exam_id 
where `exam_results`.student_id = $sid
```

So how do I put it in controller and use find () etc. to query database.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use table registry or model of the table. here i am using table registry-

```
 TableRegistry::get('exams')->find('all')
    ->where(['exam_results.student_id'=>$sid])
    ->leftJoin('exam_results', 'exam_results.exam_id = exams.id');
```

you need to add the name space `use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;`

more info http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html